# Reconstruct Sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day, I was given this project in class to create a small forum, after doing everything I noticed I made a mistake by posting all replies of a topic to the topic table instead of posting it to a reply table then calling all d replies from the reply table, so I am trying to create the reply table but am confused, this is the topic table below:

```
CREATE TABLE `topics` (
`parent` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`message` longtext NOT NULL,
`authorid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
`timestamp2` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`,`id2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT              CHARSET=utf8;
```

so the problem is trying to construct a reply table from the original topic table, so I can be able to perform this query...

```
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT         INTO replies SET bla bla);
mysql_query("UPDATE topics          SET bla bla");
```

thanks in anticipation as your help will really help my CA scores

Comment: Once you create the "reply" table, you can proceed inserting the rows in the new table and deleting them from the "topic" table. I did not understand what problem you are encountering. Please explain.

Comment: Creating the reply table (structure) is the problem am having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provided enough details but as per my assumptions you have some data in your `topics` table from which you want to insert into `replies` table and then erase it from `topics`. if i am right then you need to select all data from `topics` then loop it and insert into `replies` one by one. It would be better if you explain a little bit more about your problem.

Comment: I want to start adding replies into "reply table" rather than adding the reply into topics table after the construction of the "reply table"

Comment: Create the reply table with fields you need with one extra field for topic id, make a master-detail relation, use this `topic_id` to insert/select replies against a specific topic. you can find decent example [Here](http://www.ebruni.it/en/software/os/webgui/sqledit/examples/master_detail.htm)

Comment: Thanks, but do you mean I should construct the reply table like this:

    CREATE TABLE `reply` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `topics_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `message` longtext NOT NULL,
    `reply_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp2` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`,`topic_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT              CHARSET=utf8;

If yes, how will I relate it to the "topics" table, or is it already related?